# Python's Scikit-like Text Vectorization in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, text-processing

I have been using Scikit's text vectorizer in Python for a long time:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=False,stop_words='english',ngram_range=(1, 2))
X1= vectorizer.fit_transform(X1_corpus)    
X2 = vectorizer.transform(X2_corpus)
```

This code generates a bag of words representation: it takes a list of strings where each string contains some English text (X1_corpus in the example), finds the unique set of words in all strings, and assigns an ID to each word. Then, it returns a sparse matrix where in each row we have the a representation of the corresponding string in the corpus. And each column stands for an individual word.

The entry (i,j) in the returned sparse matrix is equal to the number occurrences of the "j"th word in the "i"th entry of the original list.

Now here is my question: Is it possible to do this "text vectorization" in Matlab as efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `unique` function and it's second and third return value. Its purpose is more general as in your example, but it should give you all information you need to build your desired output - and it's reasonably fast.

Comment: I had thought about the unique function, Could you please explain that more? An important problem is the fourth line in the python code. I will need exact same words to convert a second set of texts into bag of words representation.